# What does :- do in bash script for parameters/arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-expansion

```
arg2=${arg1:-}
```

What does this do to arg1 when assigned to arg2? I don't see any differences when printing both args

Comment: From man page:  `${parameter:-word}` : Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

Comment: It does nothing *to* `arg1`; it does something *with* the (lack of a) value of `arg1`.

Comment: @Wiimm : Not entirely true. The difference is cruicial, when you program your script with `set -u` turned on (which, IMHO, is a good idea), and `arg1` is undefined. By distinguishing these cases, you can catch undefined variables.

Comment: In case of `${arg1:-}`: if unset or empty then return an empty string.